# vb.Net converting from date to string error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have 'Strict On' and am getting the error quoted below. Normally, the program breaks and would offer possible ways to correct error, but not in this case. As I am a new user to VB.Net, I need to understand why this error is happening in Strict mode and not when it is turned off.

I would be grateful if someone could show me how to correct this. I have posted the code where this is happening. Many thanks

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Date' to
>   'String'

```
ListView1.Items.Add(CDate(dr(4).ToString())).UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
```

Comment: If the fifth field in the reader is of type `DateTime`, why don't you use `rd.GetDateTime(4)` in the first place?

Comment: The listview item is expected to be of string type and you are writing a date time, remove the CDate bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ListViewItemCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttzhk9y3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has no overload that takes a `Date` but one for `String` and one for `ListVieItem`. But you are passing a `Date` which is not convertible to string implicitely. If you want to show the short date pattern you could use `ToShortDateString`:

```
ListView1.Items.Add(dr.GetDateTime(4).ToShortDateString()).UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
```

Note that i've also used `DataReader.GetdateTime`. If it's a `Date` you don't need to convert it to `String` at all. That is inefficient, less readable and could cause localization issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try change it to this.

> ListView1.Items.Add(CDate(dr(4)).ToString()).UseItemStyleForSubItems =
>   False

Comment: What you have changed

Comment: Look where the .ToString Method is called, it's called after the CDate functon and not within it.

Comment: Actually, it is working but it is showing date/time and I only need date. ie; 29/04/2013.

Comment: Change .ToString() to .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")